# Delete in circular doubly linked list connected with head

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I have two circular doubly linked list connected with head and integer elements (unordered). wanted to delete in first list contains the values in the second list. How work pointer ?  how to make this exclusion? Need to search values in the first list to delete the second list? how can I work with them? Could explain the operation of the algorithm to solve it?

Exemple:

I have two circular doubly linked lists with head.

L1: 40 100 90 20 10 32 66

L2: 60 10 46 30 80 90

I want to delete in the first list the values that are in the second. The first list will then be:

L1: 40 100 20 32 66

I would like to know how to work with the pointer of the lists in order to make this exclusion. I wanted a notion in pseudocode. I have create to code in C but I do not understand the algorithm. I need to understand how to do before.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I have two circular doubly linked lists with head.
L1: 40 100 90 20 10 32 66

L2: 60 10 46 30 80 90

I want to delete in the first list the values that are in the second. The first list will then be:


L1: 40 100 20 32 66

I would like to know how to work with the hands of the lists in order to make this exclusion. I wanted a notion in pseudocode. I have to code in C but I do not understand the algorithm. I need to understand how to do before.

Comment: What are "hands"? Did you mean "heads"?

Comment: Please edit your question and add that detail. Give us as much information about the problem as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing the pseudocode of the algorithm, then implement actual functions, which can be tested independently.

General pseudocode would be something like:

```
for each node in list1
{
    if (list2 contains node) 
    {
       remove node from list1
    }
}
```

Presuming your lists and nodes are defined something like:

```
struct Node 
{
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
    int number;
}

struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
}

// these should be instantiated somewhere
struct List* list1;
struct List* list2;
```

So, the skeleton of the function would be something like:

```
struct Node* node = list1->head;

while (node != null)
{
    // prepare the next node early
    struct Node* next = node->next;

    // check if list2 contains a matching node
    if (match(list2, node->number)) 
    {
        // remove the node properly,
        // updating whatever you need to update
        remove(list1, node);
    }

    // if it's circular, check if this
    // is the last node
    if (next == list1->head)
        break;

    node = next;
}
```

So, now you are only left with implementing two functions:

```
// returns true if any node in list contains the specified number
bool match(struct List* list, int number);

// removes the node from the list
void remove(struct List* list, struct Node* node);
```